# Sidenotes in two column texts

Tags: two-column, marginnote, sidenotes, paracol

In this text, the note is on the right side of a number of lines with curly braces and the text written vertically.

[image: litany]

How can this be achieved? I am using paracol and xelatex but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Please don't add an answer into the question. If you find yourself an answer to your question post it an answer using the "Your Answer" field below!

Comment: In a day or so you can accept your answer.  I doubt that will give you  any points, but it will remove the question from the unanswerrd list.

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{lipsum,marginnote}
\usepackage{changepage}\strictpagecheck
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}
\tikzset{remember picture}

\newtcolorbox{leftcol}[1]{%\begin{tcbdecor}{<note>}<text>\end{tcbdecor}
colback=white, boxrule=0pt, colframe=white,  arc=0pt,  outer arc=0pt,  
top=0pt,  bottom=0pt,%
check odd page,breakable,enhanced jigsaw,oversize,%
overlay={\ifoddpage\draw[decoration={brace},decorate] (frame.north east) -- 
node[rotate=-90,above=4pt] {#1} (frame.south east);%
\else\draw[decoration={brace},decorate] (frame.north east) -- 
node[rotate=-90,above=4pt] {#1} (frame.south east);\fi}}  

\newtcolorbox{rightcol}[1]{%\begin{tcbdecor}{<note>}<text>\end{tcbdecor}
colback=white, boxrule=0pt, colframe=white,  arc=0pt,  outer arc=0pt,  
top=0pt,  bottom=0pt,%
check odd page,breakable,enhanced jigsaw,oversize,%
overlay={\ifoddpage\draw[decoration={brace},decorate] (frame.north west) -- 
node[rotate=-90,above=4pt] {#1} (frame.south west);%
\else\draw[decoration={brace},decorate] (frame.north east) -- 
node[rotate=-90,above=4pt] {#1} (frame.south east);\fi}}

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{hangparacol}{mo}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2} {\begin{paracol}{#1}}{\begin{paracol}{#1}[#2]}%
\raggedright
\parindent=3em \leftskip=3em}
{\end{paracol}}
\columnratio{0.5}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcol}{I don't like TikZ decorates}
\lipsum[1]\end{leftcol}
\switchcolumn
\begin{rightcol}{I don't like TikZ decorates}
\lipsum[1]\end{rightcol}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: img]